# ValueError: could not convert string to float: left_column_pixel

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, opencv, dataframe

l can't read values of pixels from pandas in `img() opencv` here are my code and the reported errorr

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
path_csv='/home/'
npa=pd.read_csv(path_csv+"char.csv", usecols=[2,3,4,5], header=None)
nb_charac=npa.shape[0]-1

#stock the actual letters of your csv in an array
characs=[]
cpt=0
#take characters
f = open(path_csv+"char.csv", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    if cpt>=1: #skip header
        characs.append(str(row[1]))
    cpt+=1

#open your image
path_image= '/home/'
img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_image,'image1.png'))

path_save= '/home/2/'
i=0
#for every line on your csv,
for i in range(nb_charac):

    #get coordinates
    #coords=npa[i,:]
    coords=npa.iloc[[i]]
    charac=characs[i]

    #actual cropping of the image (easy with numpy)
    img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[4]),int(coords[3]):int(coords[5])]
    img_charac=cv2.resize(img_charac, (32, 32), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    i+=1



    #charac=charac.strip('"\'')
    #x=switch(charac)
    #saving the image
    cv2.imwrite(path_save+str(charac)+"_"+str(i)+"_"+str(img_charac.shape)+".png",img_charac)
    img_charac2 = 255 - img_charac
    cv2.imwrite(path_save +str(charac)+ "_switched" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac2.shape) + ".png", img_charac2)
    print(i)
```

l got the following error

```
  img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[3]),int(coords[0]):int(coords[1])]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return converter(self.iloc[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'left_column_pixel'
```

the error is related to this line of code :

```
img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[4]),int(coords[3]):int(coords[5])]
```

such that my variable coords is as follow :

```
>>> coords=npa.iloc[[1]]
>>> coords
    2    3     4     5
1  38  104  2456  2492
```

and the different values of the column 2,3,4,5 needed in image_char are :

```
>>> coords[2]
1    38
Name: 2, dtype: object
>>> coords[3]
1    104
Name: 3, dtype: object
>>> coords[4]
1    2456
Name: 4, dtype: object
>>> coords[5]
1    2492
Name: 5, dtype: object
```

l updated the line of `img_charac` as follow

```
 img_charac = img[int(float(coords[2].values[0])):int(float(coords[4].values[0])), int(float(coords[3].values[0])):int(float(coords[5].values[0]))]
```

l don't have anymore

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'left_column_pixel'
```

but l got the following error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: left_column_pixel
```

l noticed that outside the loop `img_charac` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `ValueError` occurs because you are reading the header row of your csv file within the first iteration of your for-loop. The header contains string labels which can't converted to integers:

- `for i in range(nb_charac)` will start with `i` having `0` as the first value.
- Then, `coords=npa.iloc[[i]]` will return the first row (0th row) of your csv-file.
- Since you've set `header=None` in `npa=pd.read_csv(path_csv+"char.csv", usecols=[2,3,4,5], header=None)`, you iterate over strings within your header row.

So either set `header=0` or `for i in range(1, nb_charac)`.